Performing recursive feature elimination with multiple performance metrics
I am trying to make a classifier as parsimonious as possible. To do this, I am recursively dropping features using cross validation.
In the context of my model, precision is the most important metric. However, I would also like to see how other metrics evolve as less features are fed to the model.
In particular, I would like to evaluate the models' recall and F1 scores.
rfe = RFECV(
    estimator=clf,  # An XGBClassifier instance
    step=1,
    min_features_to_select=1,
    cv=cv,  # A StratifiedKFold instance
    scoring='precision',
    # scoring=['f1', 'precision', 'recall'],  # throws error
    verbose=1,
    n_jobs=1
)

I commented-out the line that passes a list of metrics to the scoring argument because it throws an InvalidParameterError (that is, it's not happy that I passed it a list).
Is there a way to pass multiple metrics to an RFECV instance?

RFECV eliminates features one by one based on scoring function. On each iteration it goes through all remaining variables and eliminates one feature based on scoring results. Thus it needs a single number to decide which feature to remove. So it can't use several scoring functions unless they are combined somehow via custom scorer. Answering your question: you need to score rfe outputs separately if you want to get 3 separate scoring functions outputs

Hi @JohnnyCheesecutter ! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe RFECV drops features based on the importance of each feature. In my case, it would use clf.feature_importances_, which is not related to a performance metric.

according to the manual it applies scorer to your cv-folds and then selects the set of features that maximise scores on cv-folds

ok, I guess you are partly right, it do both, it removes features with least feature_importance on each step, but then it applies CV scorer to check that model performance didn't drop after removing the selected feature.

This feels like something that could be changed: treat it more like the hyperparameter tuners, exposing (all) scores in cv_results_ and with refit to determine the selection of "best" number of features. I can't immediately find an existing github Issue to that end, maybe you can add one?

@BenReiniger speak of the devil: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/28937. I literally just added this feature request, lol.

RFECV eliminates features one by one solely based on their importance. In theory, each model using k < K features can be scored by multiple metrics. However, once all possible number of features have been tested, RFECV picks the model with the greatest mean_test_score, which means that it relies on a single figure to pick the best number of features.
How RFECV works, short version:
RFE removes features based on "feature_importance". However you still need to select k parameter - number of features to use. You can do this by evaluating a scoring function on a test dataset for all possible k values. And then select k that gives best performance on Test dataset. And this is how you left with final k features. However to make this process more reliable you can repeat this process several times on CV-folds. Then average scores from test datasets for all folds.
How RFECV works, long version:

First it breaks the data using provided CV split and thus returning pairs (X_train, X_test) for each fold.
For each pair of (X_train, X_test) it applies RFE (obviously for each cv-pair RFE results might be different). So on each cv-pair on each step RFE selects k best features according to feature_importance if fitting given X_train. Then on each step for selected features it evaluates model on X_test using scorer and returns a score for the selected k features.
Now for each cv-fold (X_train, X_test) and each k value you have a score on the test fold. This scores gets averaged across all cv-folds. So you finally get pairs: (k_features, cv_test_score)
Now for each k - features selected by RFE - we have an averaged single score value. This scores are sorted and used to select k with highest score. You get best-k
Finally we run RFE again but this time on the whole X dataset targeting RFE to return exactly best-k features.

To conclude, RFECV needs a single number to decide which k value is the best. So it can't use several scoring functions unless they are combined somehow via custom scorer.
Answering your question: you need to score rfe outputs separately if you want to get 3 separate scoring functions outputs.
Also to note, because f1 already is a mixture of precision and recall it might be worth to run RFECV with scoring='f1'.

From what I see in the source code, the score is not used to eliminate features. Rather, the importance of the features (importance_getter) is used to rank them.

From the code of RFECV you can see that it uses scoring on CV to decide how many features to remove:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8721245511de2f225ff5f9aa5f5fadce663cd4a3/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py#L760C9-L760C19

Updated my answer with detailed explanation how RFECV works.

I agree with this answer. In fact, I was editing it myself, haha. Just one note: RFECV does not drop features based on the CV score on each iteration. It only uses the best score to select the best number of features. That is, it runs the whole loop from N down to min_features_to_select solely using importance_getter and once it has finished, it then uses argmax ro find the best number of features based on the score.

Cool ) Glad that we figured this out.

I slightly edited the first paragraph. Thank you for your answer (;

thx! Appreciate your help with this.
